# Use SQL Management Objects (SMO) to restore a database snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I want to restore a database snapshot using SQL Server Management objects, however I'm having a bit of a hard time finding any examples of how this might be achieved. All the samples on MSDN suggest using T-SQL to call the `RESTORE DATABASE` keywords, but as mentioned before, I'd like to use SMO instead.

Does anyone have ideas on how this might be achieved?

I don't see any members on the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database` object that would seem to indicate I can `RestoreFromSnapshot()`, for example.

Comment: read this: http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/06/01/how-to-restore-sql-server-databases-using-smo-and-powershell/

Comment: That's a restore from backup, not a restore from snapshot.

Comment: I have been looking for a way to do this after my post on using SMO for creating snapshots but never found a way. But, given the fact that Managament Studio uses .NET, there has to be way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you want, but here's a link on how to create database snapshots in SMO using powershell.  I haven't ever tried to restore a snapshot, but it should get you started.

http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=2101

Comment: I've already got a working script to create database snapshots. My question is specifically around performing a restore.